# Linked Server ODBC statement missing delimiters on reserved identifier

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, odbc

```
INSERT INTO SOMESERVER...[SomeTable] ([ID], [Timestamp]) VALUES (746, 1504500000)
```

This statement is missing delimiters for the identifiers in an ODBC trace.

```
"INSERT INTO SomeTable ( ID,Timestamp) VALUES(?,?)"
```

Therefore the statement results in an error due to the reserved word `Timestamp`. How can we add the required delimiters?

- Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit) Version 12.0.5207.0
- Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
- 4D v13 ODBC Driver 64 bits

**Update:** as a workaround, we created a service to insert the missing delimiters by intercepting the network communication between the ODBC driver and the 4D database.

Comment: Have your tried double quotes in place of the brackets? `INSERT INTO SomeTable ("ID", "Timestamp") VALUES(746,1504500000)`

Comment: Why are you using ODBC and a third party driver to access another SQL Server via a linked server?

Comment: @Scott double quotes behave the same way.

Comment: @Dan we are accessing a 4th Dimension (4D) database from SQL Server.